# Regular Expression in URL Not Working

Tags: python, regex, django, django-templates

I have below url pattern and when i trying to access its saying Page not found

```
url(r'^getrequest/(add|edit|delete)/(\d+)/', 'CMS_graph.views.test_data', name='CMS_data'),
```

i have HTML page for this pattern.

view.py

```
def test_data(request, data , id):
   title = "Got Request %s" %(request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
   print request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],data,id
   if (request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '172.20.115.137'):
       download_data(data, id)
   context = {
            "titleofpage" : title
            }
   return render(request,'test.html', context)
```

test.html

```
<h1>{{titleofpage}}</h1>
```

where i am doing wrong??
i m trying to open `http://127.0.0.1:8080/getrequest`

Comment: But you've defined the URLpattern to take the action and the ID, and the URL you're going to doesn't have those.

Comment: provide id in your url ex.,url(r'^getrequest/(add|edit|delete)/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'CMS_graph.views.test_data', name='CMS_data'),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to open `http://127.0.0.1:8080/getrequest` you would need to have specified a url pattern as `r'^getrequest/'` (note: and have the `APPEND_SLASH` setting true, which is a different story).

With the specified url pattern, any of the urls below are valid (as an example):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/getrequest/add/1
http://127.0.0.1:8080/getrequest/edit/5
http://127.0.0.1:8080/getrequest/delete/9
```

You can read more on URL dispatching in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/).